# Git reset and than pull

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-reset

In my scenario, I'm doing:

`git reset <commit>`

followed immediately by:

`git pull --ff-only`

From my understanding of git, this action should success, and just re-do (fast forward) the history that I reset.

However, I'm getting:
`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:` on many of my files, and the operation fails.

Does anyone know why isn't it working as I could expect? Thanks!

Comment: Try `git reset <commit> --hard`. But take care, `--hard` will discard the changes in the working tree and the index. If you need these changes, commit them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset` only unstage files that were just added to the index..

You need at least a `reset --hard` (if you are sure you don't have any work in progress) before a `pull` can succeed.

> re-do (fast forward) the history that I reset.

Not exactly: it will fetch and then ([`git pull --ff-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---ff-only)):

> Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status unless the current HEAD is already up-to-date or the merge can be resolved as a fast-forward.

It does not "fast-forward the history that you reset": reset has nothing to do with it: if you previously did local commits of your own, the merge would not be a fast-forward anyway, reset or not (unless you reset hard to `origin/master`, losing your local commits).

Answer (score 1):

**`git reset <commit>` is actually execute `git reset --mixed <commit>`** (because it’s default).

There has `--mixed`, `--soft` and `--hard` options for you to choose:

> --soft
>
> Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all
>   your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
>   it.
>
> --mixed
>
> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has
>   not been updated. This is the default action. If -N is specified,
>   removed paths are marked as intent-to-add.
>
> --hard
>
> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are discarded.
>
> More option of `git reset`, you can refer [git book](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

For your situation, you can use `git reset --hard <commit>` instead.